# JOINED 3 TABLES AND RETURN ONLY DISTINCT VALUES FOR MAX DATETIME

Tags: db2, max

I've been trying to do this the whole 2 weeks but seems like to no avail. 3 tables involved here. but am expecting the result would be distinct case no. for the same date & user. otherwise, it must return all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.CASENO,A.DATE,A.TIME,A.TRANNO,B.PCODE,C.PDESC,A.USER

FROM tableA A
RIGHT JOIN tableB B ON A.CASENO=B.CASENO
RIGHT JOIN tableC C ON C.PCODE=B.PCODE

WHERE A.DATE between 140124 and 140331
```

---

Result still have duplicates because not same time and tranno. See result on `CASENO.= 08088040`

```
A.CASENO   A.DATE   A.TIME   A.TRANNO   B.PCODE   C.PDESC    A.USER
08088040   140124   182516   321         TYQ      PREPLAN1   ANTHONY
08088040   140124   182131   318         TYQ      PREPLAN1   ANTHONY
36360569   140128   111056   431         CVB      POSTT1     MARIA
36360569   140310   113221   433         CVB      POSTT1     MARIA
37386911   140213   150240   230         M2P      PLANAVG    FELISE
37386911   140213   135220   223         M2P      PLANAVG    HECTOR
39222881   140128    94122   104         TYQ      PREPLAN1   ELLA
40895213   140213   164409   104         CVB      POSTT1     WINNIE
51311866   140124   103203   319         M2P      PLANAVG    BRATT
```

For same date, same user and same pcode and pdesc, caseno. 08088040 came out twice because of the time and tranno difference. here the max tranno would indicate the latest transaction done on the same case no. the max time also shows that the latest datetime action done for that particular case no. was on 24/01/2014 @ 18:25:16. For the same date and user, I just want the latest transaction details.

I've tried added the below script as the first condition but result was 0. It has also caused long delays before I could get the output.

```
WHERE A.TRANNO=(SELECT MAX(TRANNO) FROM tableA A where A.CASENO=B.CASENO)
```

FYI, the rests, eg. case no. 37386911 is considered unique because of different user, so I will want that to be returned. Meanwhile, case no.36360569 is also unique record because different date. although same user.

So, how should I achieve this please? Much of the examples I found was only showing for 1 table and 1 criteria to get distinct values.

The script should be those used for SQL DB2. I actually no background at all in SQL. Most of the query I've done earlier was based on trial and error but it was successful because of no complicated conditions like this.

Hopefully, somebody expert here can share the knowledge.

Thank you very much in advance.

Sincerely,
DeLL

Comment: He is new HERE.!!!!!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean as shouting on the topic with big CAPS. I thought just to show as topic only.

Comment: This is a classic [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, which can be nicely solved via the application of [windowing functions, such as `ROW_NUMBER()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426952/cte-to-represent-a-logical-table-for-the-rows-in-a-table-which-have-the-max-valu)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT A.CASENO, A.DATE, A.TIME, A.TRANNO, B.PCODE, C.PDESC, A.USER
FROM tableA A
RIGHT JOIN tableB B ON A.CASENO=B.CASENO
RIGHT JOIN tableC C ON C.PCODE=B.PCODE
WHERE A.DATE between 140124 and 140331
AND A.TRANNO = (SELECT MAX(TRANNO) FROM tableA A2 WHERE A2.CASENO=A.CASENO)
```

**Explanation:**

You can't use distinct to solve your problem, because you want data in the result that is not distinct to what you are filtering for. Your additional filter (WHERE) is the way to go.

**SQLFiddle (see result):** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da130/2/0

*Note: I had to change the column USER to USERN, since USER is a reserved word in the DB engine I selected.*

Comment: Hi Jenny, I've tried that earlier on. it returned 0 result. i believe that the script tried to find the max out of all results regardless the proposal number.

Comment: Maybe your table setup is different from what I rebuilt with SQLFiddle. Could you post the table definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause will be wrong for case no.36360569, because you only filter with `caseno`. The case no.36360569 has same caseno but different date,  so like @JennyO'Reilly 's sample, you will leave tranno 433 but miss tranno 431.

So you should add date comparation into your subquery. But use subquery in where clause like this is inefficent. My suggestion is using CTE table to get primary key set for tableA, then inner join the others instead of your where clause.

```
with pkset as
(SELECT
    A.CASENO,A.DATE,max(A.TRANNO) as tranno
   --,A.USER I'm not sure if user is part of the primary key set, can't figure out by your question
 FROM tableA
 GROUP BY A.CASENO,A.DATE
)
SELECT A.CASENO, A.DATE, A.TIME, A.TRANNO, B.PCODE, C.PDESC, A.USER
FROM tableA A
INNER JOIN pkset ON pkset.CASENO=B.CASENO and pkset.DATE=A.DATE and pkset.TRANNO=a.TRANNO
RIGHT JOIN tableB B ON A.CASENO=B.CASENO
RIGHT JOIN tableC C ON C.PCODE=B.PCODE
WHERE A.DATE between 140124 and 140331
```

By the way, can you update RIGHT JOIN to LEFT JOIN? Right join seemed not necessary, and may let A.* B.* have null values.