# CTE to represent a logical table for the rows in a table which have the max value in one column

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression

I have an "insert only" database, wherein records aren't physically updated, but rather logically updated by adding a new record, with a CRUD value, carrying a larger sequence.  In this case, the "seq" (sequence) column is more in line with what you may consider a primary key, but the "id" is the logical identifier for the record.  In the example below,

This is the physical representation of the table:

```
seq   id    name   | CRUD |
----|-----|--------|------|
1   | 10  | john   | C    |
2   | 10  | joe    | U    |
3   | 11  | kent   | C    |
4   | 12  | katie  | C    |
5   | 12  | sue    | U    |
6   | 13  | jill   | C    |
7   | 14  | bill   | C    |
```

This is the logical representation of the table, considering the "most recent" records:

```
seq   id    name   | CRUD |
----|-----|--------|------|
2   | 10  | joe    | U    |
3   | 11  | kent   | C    |
5   | 12  | sue    | U    |
6   | 13  | jill   | C    |
7   | 14  | bill   | C    |
```

In order to, for instance, retrieve the most recent record for the person with id=12, I would currently do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    PEOPLE P
WHERE       
    P.ID = 12
AND
    P.SEQ = (
        SELECT
            MAX(P1.SEQ)
        FROM
            PEOPLE P1
        WHERE P.ID = 12
    )
```

...and I would receive this row:

```
seq   id    name   | CRUD |
----|-----|--------|------|
5   | 12  | sue    | U    |
```

What I'd rather do is something like this:

```
WITH
    NEW_P
AS
(
    --CTE representing all of the most recent records
    --i.e. for any given id, the most recent sequence
)

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    NEW_P P2
WHERE       
    P2.ID = 12
```

The first SQL example using the the subquery already works for us.

**Question:**  How can I leverage a CTE to simplify our predicates when needing to leverage the "most recent" logical view of the table.  In essence, I don't want to inline a subquery every single time I want to get at the most recent record.  I'd rather define a CTE and leverage that in any subsequent predicate.

P.S.  While I'm currently using DB2, I'm looking for a solution that is database agnostic.

Comment: Not sure what your question is. Your data model does not seem to be scalable: as the overall table size and the number of records for each ID grows, you'll be taking increasingly more time to figure out which record is the latest. You may want to consider adding an indicator column where you'd store the flag showing which records are active (latest).

Comment: @mustaccio, while I appreciate the advice, there are other business reasons why the 'insert only' paradigm is being used.  While that could be influenced/changed down the road, it doesn't address the original question assuming the data model stays.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know what your question is. "Thoughts?" -- is that it? Adding an indicator column does not change "the 'insert only' paradigm" while it makes querying the table easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clear case for *window* (or *OLAP*) functions, which are supported by all modern SQL databases. For example:

```
WITH
    ORD_P
AS
(
   SELECT p.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq DESC) rn
   FROM people p
)
,
    NEW_P
AS 
(
    SELECT * from ORD_P
    WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    NEW_P P2
WHERE       
    P2.ID = 12
```

PS. Not tested. You may need to explicitly list all columns in the CTE clauses.

Comment: The end result is exactly what I'm looking for!  Let me add some info about this approach vs a similar approach, based on @Glenn's answer and then mark an answer.

Comment: I included an answer below inspired by @Glenn's answer, which also uses two CTEs.  In essence, its a self-join after already getting a representation of the latest sequences by id.  What are your thoughts on performance (or other differences) between the two approaches?  I'm very green on window functions (but would love to learn).

Comment: Window functions usually perform better than aggregation, especially when the latter is combined with a join, however, any speculation about performance is useless without testing it with your actual data on your actual system.

Comment: **Please clarify any misunderstanding: (part 1)**

The window function is ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq DESC).  This window function says determine the ordinal number of the row, while grouping by the 'id' column, ordering (in descendant order) by the 'seq' column.  This gets determine for every row in the result-set from the following FROM clause.

Comment: **Please clarify any misunderstanding: (part 2)**

The CTE 'ORD_P' represents the logical table with all columns from the 'people' table, grouped by 'id' and in descending order by 'seq'.  This logical table has an extra virtual column, named 'rn' which represents the ordinal row number, determined by the previous window function.  The CTE NEW_P represents the logical table with all columns from the 'ORD_P' virtual table, where the 'rn' column is equal to 1.  This will essentially be the people rows with the highest sequence for a given id.

Comment: @sparty02 -- correct, except the CTE named ORD_P does not group anything, it "returns" the entire table plus the extra "virtual" column.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you already put it together. First find the max `seq` associated with each `id`, then use that to join back to the main table:

```
WITH newp AS (
  SELECT id, MAX(seq) AS latestseq
    FROM people
    GROUP BY id
)
SELECT p.*
  FROM people p
  JOIN newp n ON (n.latestseq = p.seq)
  ORDER BY p.id
```

What you originally had would work, or moving the CTE into the "from" clause. Maybe you want to use a timestamp field rather than a sequence number for the ordering?

Comment: @mustaccio's answer is closer to what I'm looking for (not having to join back to that CTE every time I want to use it.  I included an alternate answer below, inspired by what you have, but am wondering what the pros/cons between the two approaches are in order to choose the "best" one.

Answer (score 0):

Following up from @Glenn's answer, here is an updated query which meets my original goal and is on par with @mustaccio's answer, but I'm still not sure what the performance (and other) implications of this approach vs the other are.

```
WITH
    LATEST_PERSON_SEQS AS
    (
        SELECT
            ID,
            MAX(SEQ) AS LATEST_SEQ
        FROM
            PERSON
        GROUP BY
            ID
    )
    ,
    LATEST_PERSON AS
    (
        SELECT
            P.*
        FROM
            PERSON P
        JOIN
            LATEST_PERSON_SEQS L
        ON
            (
                L.LATEST_SEQ = P.SEQ)
    )
SELECT
    *
FROM
    LATEST_PERSON L2
WHERE
    L2.ID = 12
```